# How to change and delete ArrayList order

Tags: vue.js

I'm new so sorry for asking a lot

I'd appreciate it if you could let me know.

```
<ul id="example-1">
  <li v-for="item in items">
    {{ item.message }}
    <v-btn>up</v-btn>
    <v-btn>down</v-btn>
    <v-btn>delete</v-btn>
  </li>
</ul>



// https://codepen.io/collection/naevzw/
var example1 = new Vue({
  el: '#example-1',
  data: {
    items: [
      { message: 'John', order: 1 },
      { message: 'Alie', order: 2 },
      { message: 'Kim', order: 3 },
      { message: 'Jane', order: 4 },
      { message: 'Nana', order: 5 },
    ]
  }
})
```

I'd be grateful if you could tell me how to approach it.

Comment: could you elaborate more on what your aim is ?

Comment: I want to change the 'order' value while changing the order,

I don't know how to delete the value when I click the 'delete' button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few Vue Parts to this question and a few JavaScript parts.

First, you may want to use a computed property to return a sorted version of the array based on the order property. Otherwise, you'd need to sort the array in the template.

```
computed: {
   sortedArray() {
      // All arrays have an .sort method that can help use sort. 
      // The links to the docs are below.
      return this.items.sort((a,b) => a.order - b.order)
   }
}
```

Next, when the buttons are clicked, you’ll want a method that updates the order property on the target/clicked item and any other items that need to shift around it. There are a few ways to do this, but one way will be to pass in the original order property of the item being clicked and either a -1, or +1 value to increment or decrement the current order. You could also pass in something like -99 if you want to delete that item. So the spoken logic will sound like:

*When an item is clicked, find that item in the array. Then, check if the value is -99; if it is, remove it from the array, and re-sort the remaining items. Otherwise, if the value is not -99, then find the element before or after the item that was clicked (depending if the clicked item shifted forward or backwards), and flip-flop the order of that item with the item that was clicked.*

```
methods: {
   reorder(clickedItemOrder, n){
       // Get index of original item
      clickedItemIndex = this.items.findIndex(el => el.order === clickedItemOrder)
      
      // If n === -99, we will delete the item
      if(n === -99) {
         this.items.splice(clickedItemIndex, 1); // remove the target item from the array

         // Get all items that were above the target item and shift their order down 1
         this.items.forEach((item, index) => {
            if (item.order > clickedItemOrder) {
                this.items[index].order -=1
            }
         });
         
      } else { 
         // if n is not -99 we expect it to be -1 or +1
         // First, we need the item before or after the target item
         otherItemIndex = this.items.findIndex(el => el.order === clickedItemOrder + n)
         
         // Now we flip flop the orders
         this.items[clickedItemIndex].order = this.items[clickedItemIndex].order + n
         this.items[otherItemIndex].order = this.items[otherItemIndex].order + -n
      }
}
```

Finally, we'll need to update our template to include the methods:

```
<ul id="example-1">
  <li v-for="item in items">
    {{ item.message }}
    <v-btn @click="reorder(item.order, 1)">up</v-btn>
    <v-btn @click="reorder(item.order, -1)>down</v-btn>
    <v-btn @click="reorder(item.order, -99)>delete</v-btn>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[MDN Sort Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)